# How to compare two matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix

My goal is to compare two matrices: `A` and `B` in two different files:

```
 function [Result]=test()
     A_Mat= load('fileA', 'A')
     B_Mat= load('fileB', 'B')
     Result= A_Mat == B_Mat
  end
```

The result that I want is a matrix that includes the difference between `A` and `B`.

The error that I have is:

```
error: binary operator '==' not implemented for 'scalar struct' by 'scalar struct' operations
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`load` function doesn't return what you think it returns.](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) Reading the extensive and easily comprehensible MATLAB documentation always helps.

```
function Result=test()
  load('fileA', 'A');
  load('fileB', 'B');
  Result = A == B
end
```

Comment: Good comment about `load`. The `==` operator, however, does not check for matrix equality. It checks for each element whether it's the same as the corresponding element in the other matrix. Based on the comment by the OP I think this is what he's looking for however.

Comment: I advise **against** using this approach for `load`-ing, because then lint can't tell where variables "suddenly pop into the workspace". My advice is `A = load('fileA'); A=A.A;` - it's a bit strange but helps avoid problems in the long run.

Comment: @Dev-iL That syntax is horrendous. How does this help avoid problems?

Comment: I'm glad you asked! This is actually something I heard Loren Shure say in a lecture. `mlint` usually warns you when you try using a variable before it is defined (just try writing this in the editor: `function test(), load('fileA', 'A'); A = A + A; end`. Imagine that you had `A` in your workspace, and at some point you decide to load some file that happens to have an `A` variable in it. Then your `A` will change all of a sudden and you won't know how it happened. When trying to debug it, you would look at all the assignments of `A` but won't find it there. Do you see the problem?

Comment: @Dev-iL She's obviously more qualified to make recommendations on MATLAB coding style than I am. Still, I fail to see the point. I would definitely advise against loading all variables from a MAT file (`load('file')`) because you might accidentally mess your workspace up, but I don't see how loading explicitely named variables is a problem. Also, the Code Analyzer warnings are unreliable at best. Try `function test(), load('fileA', 'A'); B = A + A; end`

Comment: Just to clarify: she didn't say you should use the same variable name for the `struct` and the end variable, this is just my way of "saving" a variable. I agree that lint is unreliable at times (as we see, it fails to recognize some problems, but at least it almost doesn't have false-positives). Sure, it's easy enough to "manually" track your loads when they are few and are concentrated, but it can get out of hand fast if you load files at different parts of a long code. I don't know what else I can say to convince you that a two-step assignment is better...

Comment: I see – I'm all for a two-step assignment, e.g. `measurementData = load('measurements', 'velocity'); v = measurementData.velocity;`! Just not `A = load('fileA'); A=A.A;`

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`isequal`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html) function.

```
isequal(A,B)
```

Comment: I tried it, it gives me just, Result = 0,  But my result must be a matrice

Comment: @Guillaume it does work. `Result` is a boolean, being `1`, or `true` when the two matrices are equal and it is `0` or `false` when they are not equal.

Comment: The problem is that OP supplied a return variable to `load`, which puts all the loaded variables into a struct array. This is not what OP intends to do.

Answer (score 0):

First, the operator `==` does work on matrices, and it returns a logical matrix of true/false (1/0) where the corresponding items are equal or different respectively. From the error you got it seems that you didn't read matrices from the file, but structs, and indeed, `==` doesn't work for structs.

You can use `isequal` for both structs and matrices. This function returns only one value - 1 or 0 (true/false).

**ADDED**

After seeing @dasdingonesin answer, who actually pointed to the exact problem, I just wanted to add that when you write

```
A_Mat= load('fileA', 'A')
```

it returns a struct as with the field `A`.

So:

```
A_Mat = s.A
```

Comment: No problem, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want the difference between `A` and `B` you should first use `load` as [dasdingonesin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39074419/5211833) suggested, and either check for full matrix equality with `isequal` or elementwise equality with `==`. The difference, however, is simply given by `-` of course:

```
isequal(A,B); % returns a boolean for full matrix equality
A==B;         % returns a logical matrix with element wise equality
A-B;          % returns a matrix with differences between the two matrices
```

Do note that `isequal` can deal with matrices of unequal size (it will simply return `0`), whilst both `==` and `-` will crash with the error `Matrix dimensions must agree`.